# Analog crosspoint switches

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, multiplexer

I am looking for analog crosspoint ICs that have a high number of channels, that can operate over 10V and are bi-directional.

Currently I am using the circuit [CD22M3494](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/cd22/cd22m3494.pdf) and I am looking for an alternative to it, so any MUX with channels less than 8x16 is pretty much out of the question.

The thing is I have been looking for alternatives for a few days now and all I find can pretty much be seen [here](http://goo.gl/CsSaj7).

And as I said I have been searching for a few days and I can find like 6-7 ICs at most that fit my demands. And I am wondering if it's just that I am really bad at searching for circuits or is this kind of IC not that common? I've been looking at big chip manufacturers websites and at some IC distributers like mouser for example.

And another thing, the AD8112/AD8113 alternatives in the link above is uni-directional if I understand the datasheet correctly right? Since it has input and outputs separately and not all the ports defined as input/output... Just want to make sure..

Comment: If you are looking for specific product recommendations, that is completely off-topic here. If you are looking for better ways to solve your problem, you need to be a lot more specific about what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Pethead Please see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines on questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not many choices available:

In an unbuffered world there is a 16 x 16 [crosspoint](http://www.analog.com/en/products/switches-multiplexers/unbuffered-analog-crosspoint-arrays/ad75019.html#product-overview) although the switch on resistance is a little higher than the device you are using, which may or may not be an issue.

It would be possible to make a 16 x 8 using an [array of crosspoints](http://www.analog.com/en/products/switches-multiplexers/unbuffered-analog-crosspoint-arrays.html) which would increase your choices, but you appear to desire a single component, which is somewhat rare now.

As mentioned by Neil_UK, it is also possible to use an array of [analogue multiplexers](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/analog-switches-multiplexers/mid-voltage.html).

Many crossbars are used in dynamic switching (on a per packet basis) in a digital world, and the need for large monolithic analogue crosspoints has simply reduced significantly over the years as most signals that would use such a device are now moved into the digital domain before being moved to a crosspoint array.

The buffered crosspoints you mention are indeed unidirectional because the outputs have analogue buffers (and gain in some cases).

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to figure out what you actually want, when all your question says is what you don't want.

Non-blocking. Let's say you have N inputs and M outputs. If you have a matrix of NM switches, then you have a totally non-blocking connection capability, and any number of inputs and outputs can be connected simultaneously. Is this what you want? This is not how the international telephone system works. It obviously cannot work like this, as you'd need a (few billion)^2 switches, and a lot of wires.

Blocking. Let's say you have an N:1 input multiplexer, and a 1:M output demultiplexer. This is the fewest number of switches to connect any input to any output, but it can support only one connection. Any one connection *blocks* the others. This is not how the international telephone system works either.

Channelised. Let's say you have a number P of N:1 input multiplexers, and P 1:M output demultiplexers. Now you can support up to P simultaneous connections between input and output. This economises on the number of switches, while allowing more than one input/output connection, is scalable by adding more channels, and permits the use of 1:N multiplexers. Apart from the hierarchy, that there are several tiers of multiplexers, this is how the international telephone system works.

Would considering a channelised connection ease your apparently impossible switch requirements?

Comment: Non-blocking I would assume, I want to be able to connect any inputs and outputs, e.g. I could connect all the X lines to just one Y line If I want to or I can have all the X lines connected to their own Y line making X different connections.